# How do I change the value of a character array inside a structure array which is being passed into a function as a pointer to the struct array? (in C)

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I am trying to parse the contents of a file into an array of a stucture. I only include the parts of the code that are of interest. The issue in the code lies in my attempting to access (*data[i]).title. My code gets stuck on this line but I dont have any idea why, I have tried messing around with syntax but haven't gotten anywhere.

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

const int amountOfLines = 100, maxLineLength = 150;

//A structure to store different elements of data for each game review
typedef struct Element Element;
struct Element{
    char title[60];
};

void parsingFile(FILE * file, Element * data[amountOfLines]);

int main(){
    FILE * ignData = fopen("t4_ign.csv", "r");    
    Element * data[amountOfLines];
    parsingFile(ignData, data);
}

void parsingFile(FILE * file, Element * data[amountOfLines]){
    for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++){
        char buffer[maxLineLength];
        fgets(buffer, maxLineLength, file);
        char * token = strtok(buffer, ",");
        strcpy((*data[i]).title, token);
        printf("%s is the title\n", (*data[i]).title);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have `char bin[50];` followed by (essentially) `fgets(bin, 150, file);` Does that make much sense do you think?

Comment: As for another *major* problem: You have an array of pointers, but you never make the pointers actually point anywhere. Why do you have an array of pointers to begin with?

Comment: What do you mean by "gets stuck"? Does it pause? Or does it crash?

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of issues.

```
    Element * data[amountOfLines];
    parsingFile(ignData, data);
```

`data` is allocated but never initialized. It will contain garbage. So `*data[i]` is dereferencing garbage. You either need to pre-initialize `data` with Elements, or make `parsingFile` responsible for allocating Elements and placing them on `data`.

As the caller does not know how many lines will be in `parsingFile`, it would also make sense to let `parsingFile` allocate and return the Elements array and their elements.

---

```
        fgets(buffer, maxLineLength, file);
        char * token = strtok(buffer, ",");
        strcpy((*data[i]).title, token);
```

The `maxLineLength` is 150. `buffer` and thus `token` could be as large as 150 bytes, but `title` can only hold 60.

Instead of hard coding the size of the title, make the title a character pointer and [`strdup`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strdup) the token.

```
typedef struct {
    char *title;
} Element;

...

   // Use the size of the buffer so the buffer size and read size are
   // never out of sync.
   fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file);
   char * token = strtok(buffer, ",");
   (*data[i]).title = strdup(token);
```

---

Here's one way to rewrite this code. Rather than using fixed size constants, or awkwardly passing around arrays and their size, it uses a struct to collect them together. All operations on that struct are in functions to make it easy to work with and debug.

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<assert.h>

typedef struct {
    // Store a pointer rather than a fixed size string.
    char *title;
} Element;

// A single struct to encapsulate the array and it size.
typedef struct {
    // Store a list of pointers, not copies of the elements.
    //
    // This could be made generic by storing a `void **`, but that's advanced.
    Element **data;
    // Also store the size of the data.
    size_t size;
} Elements;

// Have a function for creating structs, even if it's simple now.
// It might get complicated later. This is separate from initializing.
// For example, we don't allocate memory for title. That would be a
// waste.
Element *Element_new() {
    return malloc(sizeof(Element));
}

Elements *Elements_new() {
    return malloc(sizeof(Elements));
}

void Elements_init(Elements *elements) {
    elements->data = NULL;
    elements->size = 0;
}

Element *Elements_get(Elements *elements, size_t i) {
    assert( i < elements->size);
    return elements->data[i];
}

// Isolate the error-prone process of growing the array.
// This simplifies using Elements and offers an opportunity to
// optimize later.
void Elements_grow(Elements *elements, size_t by) {
    size_t new_size = elements->size + by;
    elements->data = realloc(elements->data, sizeof(Element*) * new_size);
    elements->size += by;
}

// Same here, isolate a discrete process.
void Elements_append(Elements *elements, Element *element) {
    Elements_grow(elements, 1);
    elements->data[elements->size-1] = element;
}

Elements *parsingFile(FILE * file) {
    // Use descriptive names.
    Elements *elements = Elements_new();
    Elements_init(elements);

    // Allocate the buffer outside the loop to be reused.
    // An optimizer will probably do this anyway, but it's
    // easier to understand.
    //
    // Use BUFSIZ. I/O happens in blocks and BUFSIZ is often
    // close to the block size.
    char buffer[BUFSIZ];

    // Read until you're done, not a fixed number of times.
    //
    // Use the size of the buffer so the buffer and read sizes will
    // never get out of sync.
    while( fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file) != NULL ) {
        char *token = strtok(buffer, ",");

        // We don't need to initialize this Element because we're
        // going to replace the title with our own pointer anyway.
        Element *elem = Element_new();

        // Copy the token from the buffer to the struct.
        // This uses exact enough memory.
        elem->title = strdup(token);

        Elements_append(elements, elem);
    }

    return elements;
}

int main() {
    FILE *ignData = fopen("t4_ign.csv", "r");
    Elements *elements = parsingFile(ignData);

    for( size_t i = 0; i < elements->size; i++ ) {
        printf("%zu: %s\n", i, Elements_get(elements, i)->title);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this enabled me to fix my issue and learn a few things too! I can't upvote your answer as my account is too new, so I thought I'd say thanks

Comment: @PatrickFarmer You're welcome, I'm glad it was of use.